# ASP.Net identity, Users in role are always empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have implemented ASP.Net identity with some custom properties following this article -

http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/06/22/ASPNET-Identity-20-Customizing-Users-and-Roles.aspx

Everything works well, except. I want to get users under specific role (e.g. Get me all the users under Admin role).

I tried following ways to retrieve the users -

```
            var userRole = _roleManager.Roles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == role.Name);
            var usersInRole = _userManager.Users.Where(m => m.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == userRole.Id));
            var usersInRole2 = _userService.GetUsers().Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == userRole.Id));
```

Where `_roleManager` is of type `ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole>`. `_userManager`is of type `ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>`.

I am unable to get Roles under user in `_userManager` and `_userService`

PS : `_userService` is service that extends IRepository which queries `DbSet<ApplicationUser>`.

I can see Roles being properly mapped in table `ApplicationUserRoles` and I get expected result when I do `_userManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Admin");`.

What could've gone wrong with this?

Rahul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out where the issue was -

Initially the table ApplicationUserRoles had only primary key definitions, not the foreign key mapping (many to many mapping)..

I added this in `OnModelCreating`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().HasKey((ApplicationUserRole r) => new { UserId = r.UserId, RoleId = r.RoleId });

//added these definitions
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(p => p.Roles).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasMany(p => p.Users).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(p => p.RoleId);
```

This completed the relationship and now I can see the `Users` under `Roles` and vice versa.

This resulted issue while updating the database, however I just had to do some changes in migration -

> The object 'PK_Dbo.ApplicationUserRole' is dependent on column
>   'UserId'. ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN UserId failed because one or more
>   objects access this column.

All I did is, I went to the migration file and moved these lines above `DropColumn`

```
DropIndex("dbo.ApplicationUserRole", new[] { "ApplicationUser_Id" });
DropIndex("dbo.ApplicationUserRole", new[] { "ApplicationRole_Id" });
DropPrimaryKey("dbo.ApplicationUserRole");
```

This solved the `update-database` exceptions as well.

Rahul

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Entity Framework, it sounds like you are being caught out by lazy loading (since the roles are being added to the database but not when requested from a queryable).

Try something like the following:

```
_userManager.Users.Include(x => x.Roles).Where(m => m.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == userRole.Id));
```